# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod in LogicApps

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps

For this line of code in Powershell I used an HTTP connector in Logic Apps using Joey Cai's advice.

`$body_login = @{"method"="login";"username"="qq";"password"="qqq"} | ConvertTo-Json`

Now, I have this line of code in Powershell.  How do I do the equivalent in LogicApps?

`$Conn = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_login -Headers $header -Body $body_login`

Do I use the same HTTP connector or do I need something else?  It's the Invoke-RestMethod syntax that I'm unsure of in Logic Apps.
I will need the output in JSON format, so I can parse it.

Thanks for the first answer.  I need to know what to put in the uri, header and body.  Here is the rest of the code which I should have provided before.

```
$baseuri = "https://test"
$header = @{
    "Accept" = "text/json"
    "Content-Type" = "text/json"
}
$G_header = @{"Accept" = "text/json"}

Write-Output "Login ..."
$uri_login = $baseuri + "SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
$body_login = @{"method"="login";"username"="qqq";"password"="qqq"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Conn = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_login -Headers $header -Body $body_login
$SessionID = $conn.sessionID</code>
```

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: Hi Joey,  With what you showed me I got a gateway timeout.  However when I put the content type to text/json and did the body like this it worked.  {
  "method": "login",
  "password": "qqq",
  "username": "qqq"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I do the equivalent in LogicApps?

As I have provided before, use `HTTP` connector.

[image]

> I will need the output in JSON format, so I can parse it.

You could use [`Compose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations) to work with data in JSON format.

1.Add Headers/Body which you want into `Compose`.

2.Add Outputs into `Parse JSON`. Copy the HTTP response Headers/Body info, and click use sample payload to generate schema, then parse Headers in it.

3.Use `Initialize variable` to get info what you want such as Date.

[image]

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Logic Apps and the built-in HTTP action, you can create automated tasks and workflows that regularly send requests to any HTTP or HTTPS endpoint.

1. Sign in to the Azure portal. Open your logic app in Logic App Designer.
2. Under the step where you want to add the HTTP action, select New step.
3. To add an action between steps, move your pointer over the arrow between steps. Select the plus sign (+) that appears, and then select Add an action.
   [image]
4. Under Choose an action, in the search box, enter "http" as your filter. From the Actions list, select the HTTP action.
5. Select HTTP action

For your scenarion you can use [Basic Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#basic-authentication).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I could not have done it without Joey

```
<code>
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": 
"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06- 
01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "HTTP_2": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "FORMAT": "payload",
                    "FROM": 0,
                    "GRIDID": "PROP",
                    "GRIDVIEW": "1",
                    "HITS": 100,
                    "ORDERBY": "PR_DATESOLD",
                    "PROFILE": [
                        {
                            "PR_NAME": "G*",
                            "PR_USER1": "GENERATED"
                        }
                    ],
                    "sessionID": "@body('Parse_JSON3')['sessionID']"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "@variables('uri_DefGrid')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Parse_JSON3": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "Initialize_Header": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "Header",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "{\"Accept\":\"text/json\",\"Content- 
 Type\":\"text/json\"}"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_body_login": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_body_DefGrid": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "body_DefGrid",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "json(@{body('HTTP_2')})"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "HTTP_2": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_body_login": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "body_login",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "json(@{triggerBody()})"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_DefGrid": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_DefGrid",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://test/SPDEDMHAPI.GRIDGET"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_login": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_login": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_login",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://test/SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_Header": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_uri_logout": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "uri_logout",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "https://test/SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGOUT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_body_DefGrid": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Logout": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "method": "logout",
                    "sessionID": "@body('Parse_JSON3')['sessionID']"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "@variables('uri_logout')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_logout": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "Parse_JSON3": {
            "inputs": {
                "content": "@triggerBody()",
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {
                        "RLS_WHERE": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/RLS_WHERE",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "contact": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "error": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "errorId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "fullName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "labellanguage": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "language": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "params": {
                            "properties": {
                                "WOPARTSOPT": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "WOPARTSOPT"
                            ],
                            "title": "The Params Schema",
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "role": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sessionID": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "success": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "userEmail": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/userEmail",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "success",
                        "message",
                        "sessionID",
                        "language",
                        "labellanguage",
                        "error",
                        "errorId",
                        "fullName",
                        "role",
                        "contact",
                        "RLS_WHERE",
                        "userEmail",
                        "params"
                    ],
                    "title": "The Root Schema",
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_uri_DefGrid": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "ParseJson"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "HTTP": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "method": "login",
                    "password": "qqq",
                    "username": "qqq"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "text/json",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "https://test/SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 4
            },
            "type": "Http"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {}
}
</code>
```